# Error in sepia effect opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a filter which will create a sepia look for all pictures. But I get some spots in my filtered image which are blue and cyan. I think it might be overflow but I tried to account for that and it didnt give me the affect I was looking for. I'm not sure whats wrong. The link to original is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd0esc8tef3smae/Lampard.jpg and after the modification, it becomes https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9n9lrhoi1qqs53/Lampard_blue.jpg

```
def filter3(path, cv2):
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.namedWindow("Filter 3")
img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 
newImg = img
(i,j,k) = img.shape
for x in xrange(i):
    for y in xrange(j):
        b = img[x,y,0]
        g = img[x,y,1]
        r = img[x,y,2]
        if(k == 4):
            newImg[x,y,0] = np.uint16(b * 0.272 + g * 0.534 + r * 0.131)
            newImg[x,y,1] = np.uint8(b * .349 + g * 0.686 + r * 0.168)
            newImg[x,y,2] = np.uint8(b * 0.393 + g * 0.769 + r * 0.189)
            # newB = np.uint16(b * 0.272 + g * 0.534 + r * 0.131)
            # newG = np.uint16(b * .349 + g * 0.686 + r * 0.168)
            # newR = np.uint16(b * 0.393 + g * 0.769 + r * 0.189)
            # if(newB > 255):
            #   newImg[x,y,0] = np.uint8(255)
            # else: 
            #   newImg[x,y,0] = np.uint8(newB)
            # if(newG > 255):
            #   newImg[x,y,1] = np.uint8(255) 
            # else: 
            #   newImg[x,y,1] = np.uint8(newB)
            # if(newR > 255):
            #   newImg[x,y,2] = np.uint8(255) 
            # else: 
            #   newImg[x,y,2] = np.uint8(newB)

            newImg[x,y,3] = img[x,y,3]
        else:
            newImg[x,y,0] = np.uint16(b * 0.272 + g * 0.534 + r * 0.131)
            newImg[x,y,1] = np.uint8(b * .349 + g * 0.686 + r * 0.168)
            newImg[x,y,2] = np.uint8(b * 0.393 + g * 0.769 + r * 0.189)
            # if(newB > 255):
            #   newImg[x,y,0] = np.uint8(0)
            # else: 
            #   newImg[x,y,0] = np.uint8(newB)
cv2.imshow("Filter 3", newImg)
return newImg
```

Comment: I know you're rep's too low to include an image, but can you provide a link to one?

Comment: The link to the original is https://www.dropbox.com/sc/nrczah6uw18fra7/541JidEYrd

Comment: And after the transformation,it becomes - https://www.dropbox.com/sc/2spt6ad2qco0f6m/XeNuCj8omP

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion problem is with types. Python thinks that after operation you want to integer. Each channel has 8 bits. After calculation when you will get value 256 (100000001) python will read only first 8 bits (00000001). Because of that you have a little bit strange image.
In my case works this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
newImage = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
i, j, k = img.shape
for x in xrange(i):
    for y in xrange(j):
    R = img[x,y,2] * 0.393 + img[x,y,1] * 0.769 + img[x,y,0] * 0.189
    G = img[x,y,2] * 0.349 + img[x,y,1] * 0.686 + img[x,y,0] * 0.168
    B = img[x,y,2] * 0.272 + img[x,y,1] * 0.534 + img[x,y,0] * 0.131
    if R > 255:
        newImage[x,y,2] = 255
    else:
        newImage[x,y,2] = R
    if G > 255:
        newImage[x,y,1] = 255
    else:
        newImage[x,y,1] = G
    if B > 255:
        newImage[x,y,0] = 255
    else:
        newImage[x,y,0] = B

cv2.imshow('image',newImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Maybe it's not nice code, but I'm not familiar with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but you can refer below C++ code works fine for me.

```
Mat src=imread("Lampard.jpg",1);
Mat SepiaKernel = (Mat_<float>(4,4) << 0.189, 0.769, 0.393, 0,\
                                       0.168, 0.686, 0.349, 0,\
                                       0.131, 0.534, 0.272, 0,\
                                       0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1);
Mat dst;
transform(src, dst, SepiaKernel);
imshow("src",src);
imshow("sepia",dst);
waitKey();
```

**Result:-**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image array to float before applying the sepia filter. Also using `cv2.transform` will be much faster than iterating over all the pixels. This code can be used

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('messi.jpg')
original = img.copy()
img = np.array(img, dtype = np.float64)
img = cv2.transform(img, np.matrix([[ 0.393, 0.769, 0.189],
                                    [ 0.349, 0.686, 0.168],
                                    [ 0.272, 0.534, 0.131]]))
img[np.where(img>255)] = 255
img = np.array(img, dtype = np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("original", original)
cv2.imshow("Output", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Original]
[image: Sepia colored]